# Custom QVariant troubles

Tags: c++, qt

I am discovering Custom Types with QVariant and tried to implement it in my project.
The problem is, it seems like it creates an object with the default constructor when I thought it would use the copy constructor...

Maybe there is something I don't understand...

Here is my custom class :

Parameter.h

```
#ifndef PARAMETER_H
#define PARAMETER_H
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaType>

#include "variable.h"
#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class Parameter : public Variable, public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    Parameter();
    Parameter(QString name, int min, int max, int val, QObject *parent);
    Parameter(const Parameter &source);

private:
    int m_value;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Parameter)

#endif // PARAMETER_H
```

Parameter.cpp

## include "parameter.h"

```
Parameter::Parameter() : Variable()
{
    qDebug()<<"Default constructor";
    m_value = 0;
    setName("Test");
}

Parameter::Parameter(QString name, int min, int max, int val, QObject     *parent)
: Variable(name, min, max), QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    qDebug()<<"constructor";
    m_value = val;
}

 Parameter::Parameter(const Parameter &source)
     : Variable(source.getName(), source.getMin(), source.getMax()),
      QAbstractTableModel(),
      m_value(source.m_value)
{
    qDebug()<<"copy constructor";  
}
```

I create an instance of Parameter in a class MainWindow. The following code is an extract of the constructor of this class :

```
Parameter *param = new Parameter("Param",0,100,10, this);
QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(param);
Parameter op = v.value<Parameter>();
qDebug()<< op.getName();
```

The output of this code is :

```
constructor
Default constructor 
Default constructor
"Test"
```

I would like to understand why the default constructor is called twice. And what I should do so that it calls the copy constructor instead (in order to get the object I created, whose name is "Param)

Thank you a lot for your answers :)

Comment: Should it be `QVariant::fromValue(*param);` ?

Comment: That was it ahahha - Thank you so much... and sorry for now I realise it was a very dumb question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store **pointer** in your `QVariant` instead of value. But want to retrieve value.

> If the value cannot be converted, a default-constructed value will be returned.

so `v.value<Parameter>();` returns a default-constructed object as `Parameter*` cannot be converted to `Parameter`.

Comment: Thank you :)
Now, if I want to use the following, 
    `QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(*param);

    Parameter *op = v.value<Parameter*>();

    qDebug()<< op->getName();`
I get this error : static assertion failed qobject_cast requires the type to have a Q_object macro
Would you happen to know why ?

Comment: If you store value, retrieve value, if you store pointer, retrieve pointer.